# Javascript doesn't work if it's linked from jsp in my project

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

my js doesn't work in my dynamic web project if I linked it from a jsp, but if i put it in the jsp it works fine. Same for every js code.
I don't know what to do, jquery is imported...
The javascript code is correct because it work fine in the same jsp, but if I put it in a *.js file it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CheckUp - Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SharedCSS/Header.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SharedCSS/Footer.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HomepageCSS/CarouselSlider.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HomepageCSS/HomepageIcon.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- INCLUSIONE HEADER -->
    <%@include file="Shared/Header.jsp"%> 
    
    <!-- INCLUSIONE SLIDER -->
    <%@include file="Homepage/CarouselSlider.jsp"%>

    <!-- INCLUSIONE ICONE -->
    <%@include file="Homepage/HomepageIcon.html"%>
    
    <!-- INCLUSIONE FOOTER-->
    <%@include file="Shared/Footer.jsp"%> 
    
    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/HomepageJS/CarouselSlider.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Here "CarouselSlider.js":

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
carousel();

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length };
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
}
```

and "CarouselSlider.jsp":

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <img class="mySlides" src="Img/TAMPONE-CORONAVIRUS-COVID.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="Img/test-udito.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="Img/Prenota.jpg">
    <div class="w3-center w3-display-bottommiddle">
        <div class="w3-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
        <div class="w3-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
I solved. it was a path problem. I used "../" instead of "./"

Comment: I have already tried to change the relative path (../js/...) to an absolute one (/js/.....)

Comment: When you open the JSP in your browser, how does the browser address bar look like? The location of your JS file needs to be relative to the address displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console and verify the file is actually loading. Most likely you have a bad path.

Also your type attribute is bad. In HTML5 it is also redundant just remove it.

```
<script src="../correct/path/to/js/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
<script src="../js/HomepageJS/CarouselSlider.js"></script>
```

Also, it will be more clear if you can show the path structure of your .jsp and .js files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

This can be helpful for you:

```
<script src="../js/HomepageJS/CarouselSlider.js"></script>
```